# Listening a file, and get the 5 previous lines before the line matching occurence

Tags: bash, file, grep

I'm using tail -F file.log to listen a file, and need to work on the 5 previous lines before the line matching my occurence using grep.

tail is line per line, so I can't.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -F file | grep -B 5
```

`tail -F` follows, of course, and `grep -B` prints the specified number of lines before each match.